# How do I use a Button in a swiftUI view?

Tags: button, swiftui

How do I use a Button in a swiftUI view? The view will just contain the Button and some Texts. When the button is tapped it will execute a function that will change the words in the Texts and then wait for another Button tap and repeat. I could readily do it with UIKit but with swiftUI a Button seems to be more involved than I expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the way you can do it is to create a custom button that you can use on many views.

```
/// Custom button that can be used in any view
struct CustomButton: View {

  // This is the custom method called from other views
  var action: () -> ()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Button(action: { self.action() }) {
        Text("Tap me")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then, you can use it this way on your main view and change the text for example. You can add anything you want in the changeMyText method.

```
// Your main view
struct ContentView: View {

  // Keep track of the change of a tap
  @State private var buttonTapped = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack(spacing: 50) {

      Text(buttonTapped ? "My second Text" : "My first text")

      // Declare your custom button with desired functions
      CustomButton(action: { self.changeMytext() })
    }
  }

  // Method where you perform whatever you need
  func changeMytext() {
    self.buttonTapped.toggle()
  }
}
```

Comment: In this example, what causes ContentView to be re-displayed after a button tap? I expected to see something analogous to UIKit's 'setNeedsDisplay' but I don't see it. Does any change to ContentView trigger display?

Comment: ContentView is a struct and because of that, static. The object that triggers the View change is @State. Every time the "@State" value changes, the View itself recalculates what changes should be displayed, and rewrites itself with new changes. This is a big difference compare to UIKit, and this is why in SwiftUI you don't need a ViewController anymore.